# C# reference variable, does making one null make the other null?

Tags: c#, reference

I have a question about how C# works.

```
m_MyClass = new MyClass();
Dispatcher.m_MyClass = m_MyClass;
```

If I set m_MyClass = null, will that automatically make Dispatcher.m_MyClass null?

Comment: Variables are storage locations. You put things inside of them. When you assign the contents of one storage location to another, you make a *copy* of the contents of the source storage location and put it in the target location. Later, you assign another value to the source storage location. It has *zero* impact on the target storage location, or *any* other storage location for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. Assigning a different value to a variable of a reference has no effect on other 
references.

Only modifying fields of an instance or using properties or methods which modify those fields will have an effect:

```
m_MyClass = new MyClass();
Dispatcher.m_MyClass = m_MyClass;

m_MyClass.MyProp = null;
// Dispatcher.m_MyClass.MyProp == null
```

Comment: I see. I've been studying C# lately, but didn't understand this section.

Answer (score 4):

No.  The variable assignment is assigning a copy of the reference *by value*.  Changing the variable after the assignment will not affect the `Dispatcher.m_MyClass` field/property.